# How to stop JScrollPane from automatically updating the Scroll Bar value?

Tags: java

I use in my app a JscrollPane with a BoxLayout panel inside. I it to never change value after repainting. How can I do this?

I tried
`pane.getHorizontalScrollBar().setValue()`
but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Why are you repainting the panel. Post a proper [mre] demonstrating the problem so we can understand the context of your question better.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the Horizontal (and/or) Vertical scrollbar policies:

```java
pane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
pane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
```

You could also mess around with the Viewport's size (max & mins), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution.
Now I repaint panel inside scrollpane instead of scrollpane and it works.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).